# How to insert an anchor tag into a list item with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list item which has an HTML class name:

```
<li class="navi"> HOME </li>
```

Using JavaScript, I want to insert an anchor tag in that list item, via the list item's class name. Anchor is here:

```
<a href="#HOME">HTML</a>
```

What do I need to do for this to become:

```
<li class="navi"><a href="#HOME" >HOME</a> </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pure vanilla javascript:

```js
function makelink() {
  var li = document.getElementsByClassName('navi')[0];
  li.innerHTML = '<a href="#hOME">HTML</a>';
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="navi"> HOME </li>
</ul>

<button onclick="makelink()">click here to make HOME link</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("ul").append("<li class='navi'><a href='#HOME' >HOM E</a></li>")  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="navi"> HOME </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$li = $('li.navi');
$li.html("<a href='#"+ $li.text() +"'>"+ $li.text() +"</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without complete code example showing what you are attempting, we are guessing. But you could try:

```
$('.navi').append('<a href="#HOME">HOME</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```
var listItem = document.querySelector('navi');
var name = listItem.innerText;
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
var anchor.href = "#"+name;
var anchor.innerText = name;
listItem.appendChild(newNode);
```